# Construct reshape tibble into one row

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, tidyr

I have this tibble

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(id = c(1, 2, 3), n = c(1, 2, 1), max = c(-10, 2, 3), class = c(0, 0, 0), Time = c(1, 1, 1))     
id     n   max class  Time
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   -10     0     1
2     2     2     2     0     1
3     3     1     3     0     1
```

The column `class` and `Time` are constants, so I want to `id` column to be concatenated with the `n` and `max` column such that.

```
  class  Time `1_n` `1_max` `2_n` `2_max` `3_n` `3_max`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     0     1     1     -10     2       2     1       3
```

I tried it with `pivot_wider` but could not get it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from = "id", values_from = n:max, 
            names_glue = "{id}_{.value}", names_vary = "slowest")

# A tibble: 1 × 8
  class  Time `1_n` `1_max` `2_n` `2_max` `3_n` `3_max`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     0     1     1     -10     2       2     1       3
```